# Wordpress не работает Jquery Ui Tabs

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

Имеется статистический Html

```
<ul class="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Your Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Another Title</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Когда, вывожу функцией wp_nav_menu, то отобржаеться, только тайитл ссылки меню, и в консоли генерируются совсем другие стили..

```
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
</ul>
```

Помогите, как разрешить данную проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать 
`'items_wrap'=> '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',`
в нем вы можете задать вывод ваших ссылок как вам удобно, подробней читайте тут 
http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu